# Need to merge two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, sql-function

I have one query with nothing special about it.  Basic select and lots of joins, but nothing advanced.

I have a second query that uses a cursor and pivot.  This is about as advanced a query as I've ever done (SQL noob).  What I'd like to do is stick the second query inside the first and somehow use the row outputs of the first query into the second.  Confusing, I know.

Second query looks like this:

```
declare @num as varchar(50)
declare pno cursor for
  select
    p.part_key
  from
    part_table as p
  where
    p.part_status = "Prod"

open pno
fetch next from pno into @num

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  select
     @num as "Part Number",
     [id1] as "Data1",
     [id2] as "Data2",
     [id3] as "Data3"
  from
     select
       t1.qty * t2.cost as ExtCost,
       t2.opcode as opcode
     from
       table1 as t1
     join table2 as t2
       on t1.id = t2.id
     where
       t1.part_key = @num
  ) t
  pivot
    (sum(extcost) for opcode in [id1], [id2], [id3])) pvt

  fetch next from pno into @num
end
close pno
deallocate pno
```

This query spits out exactly what I  want, and is the only way I know that I can get that information.  And the first query spits out different information but referencing the same group of 'parts' I select in this pivot query.  So, what I'd like to do is for each row (i.e. part_key) in the first query I want to spit out the data from the second query related to that part_key.

So, for example, the first query spits out something like this:

> PART KEY | q1DATA1 | q1DATA2

And the second query spits out:

> PART KEY | [id1] | [id2] | [id3]

What I want to do is this:

> PART KEY | q1DATA1 | q1DATA2 | [id1] | [id2] | [id3]

I've tried looking at sub-queries, but those seem to be rather restrictive to what I'm doing.

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Both queries can be simplified into one by just adding another `JOIN` to the second query. I understand that these `FROM`/`WHERE` clauses should do the trick :

```
FROM
    part_table as p
    INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.part_key = p.part_key
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE
    p.part_status = 'Prod'
```

When it comes to pivoting the output, I do suspect that what you are trying to accomplish can be done using *conditional aggregation*.

```
SELECT
    p.part_key,
    p.q1DATA1,
    p.q1DATA2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.opcode = '[id1]' THEN t1.qty * t2.cost ELSE 0 END) id1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.opcode = '[id2]' THEN t1.qty * t2.cost ELSE 0 END) id2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.opcode = '[id3]' THEN t1.qty * t2.cost ELSE 0 END) id3,
FROM
    part_table as p
    INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.part_key = p.part_key
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE
    p.part_status = 'Prod'
GROUP BY 
    p.part_key,
    p.q1DATA1,
    p.q1DATA2
```

NB : this is standard ANSI SQL that should work on most RDBMS.